# Function "was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and get a beginner's mistake:

> myclass.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>   myclass.cpp: 14:16: error: ‘func’ was not declared in this scope

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass{
public:
    int func(int);
};

int MyClass::func(int a){
    return a*2;
}

int main(){
    cout << func(3);
}
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: It's a method of your class, so where's your class instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int main(){
    cout << func(3);
}
```

`func` is not a global function; it is a member function of the class. You need an instance of the class to access it.

For example:

```
int main()
{
   MyClass obj;
   std::cout<< obj.func(3);
}
```

Comment: Thanks all, but you were first!

Answer (score 4):

`func` is a member function, so it must be invoked through an object. For example:

```
int main()
{
    MyClass obj;

    std::cout << obj.func(3); // 6
}
```

In your example, you treated it as a free function, so the compiler looked for a function with that name. Since it could not find it, it issued a compiler error.

Answer (score 3):

`func` is a member function of `MyClass`. To call it, you need an object of `MyClass` type to invoke it on:

```
int main(){
    MyClass m; // Create a MyClass object
    cout << m.func(3);
}
```

Alternatively, you could make `func` a `static` member function, which means that it is not associated with any particular instance of the class. However, you would still need to qualify its name as belonging to the `MyClass` class:

```
class MyClass{
public:
    static int func(int);
};

int MyClass::func(int a){
    return a*2;
}

int main(){
    cout << MyClass::func(3);
}
```